# Unknown blob error when attempting a docker push

Tags: docker

I have a build process that builds several images and pushes them to a release repo in an internal Jfrog instance, however one of the image pushes started to consistently fail all of a sudden.

Getting the following error and am stumped as to how I should debug further:

```
make pushImage
docker push some-repo/path/to/image:tag
The push refers to a repository [some-repo]
[image id 1]: Preparing
[image id 2]: Preparing
[image id 3]: Preparing
[image id 4]: Preparing
[image id 2]: Waiting
[image id 3]: Waiting
[image id 4]: Waiting
unknown blob
make: *** [pushImage] Error 1
```

From my research I have found that this typically means a layer is missing from the target repository and so the missing layer needs to be added. I however don't really understand how to:

- figure out which specific layer is actually missing
- how and where to populate the missing layer

Things I have tried unsuccessfully:

- turning on debug mode on the docker daemon to see if the logs output anything more meaningful
- rebuilding a new image with caching disabled
- ran docker inspect to find the sha digests of each layer in an attempt to match them to the image IDs to understand which specific layer is missing, however the image IDs and the layer's sha digests do not match **EDIT**: This useful blog post explains why this occurs - https://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/
- manually copied the image from a sandbox repo into the release repo in an effort to populate the missing layer
- deleting the images that share the problematic tag in container registry in the event there was a corrupted layer and attempting to re-push

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the team managing the internal Jfrog instance was caching images on a cluster. Turning off server-side caching solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).